# How to accept Touch ID on macOS without triggering a Prompt

Tags: xcode, macos, keychain, touch-id, face-id

Is there a way to accept Touch ID, without triggering the default MacOS Touch ID prompt? Or is there a way to heavily customize the default Touch ID prompt?

I have seen 1Password do it, so it is possible.

I have tried following these tutorials, but they didn't work

[Accessing Keychain Items with Face ID or Touch ID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/accessing_keychain_items_with_face_id_or_touch_id)

[Logging a User into Your App with Face ID or Touch ID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id)

I have also read about Passkeys, but I don't think it will work because it's for Web Authentication.

Any pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

This is a screenshot of how 1Password does it:

[image]

Comment: Try Local Authentication it’s an Apple Framework it allows some customization.

Comment: I tried local authentication, but it doesn't allow prompt customization. The first link in the question covers the local authentication tutorial.

Comment: This is a really interesting question; is that prompt is coming from 1Password (i.e. not triggered by an action in iTerm2)? Is this a Touch ID prompt (i.e. holding your finger on the fingerprint sensor authenticates, or it takes you to the "real" system TouchID prompt)? What happens in this UI if Touch ID fails? Do you get a custom prompt to enter your password?

Comment: @TheNextman here 1Password is acting as an SSH Agent provider -- https://developer.1password.com/docs/ssh/agent/  So this prompt gets triggered every time I try to SSH into a server or do a git pull/push. This is a Touch ID prompt, and holding a finger unlocks it. There is no other prompt.  If Touch ID fails with multiple attempts, it asks for a 1Password master password. I, too, find this experience fascinating because I have never seen this with any other Mac App.

Comment: It might be a private key saved in the keychain using biometrics. Not sure if you can alter the UI, as I've never used it on macOS. I wasn't able to customize anything on iOS, but might be worth to take a look at. Specifically the [`kSecUseAuthenticationUI`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecuseauthenticationui) key

Comment: Typically it's not possible to customize the prompt, for security reasons it should be consistent across the OS and applications. Otherwise a malicious application can prompt in a way that masks what is being unlocked by the authentication. That's why this issue is so surprising since 1Password appears to be doing exactly that (either by private API or somehow otherwise manipulating the TouchID prompt)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do isn't supported, at least not officially.
You can try using custom UI overlay. The code is in [swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/).

```
import SwiftUI
import LocalAuthentication

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var authenticationResult: AuthenticationResult?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Touch ID Authentication (add your custom text here)")
                .padding()

            Button("Authenticate with Touch ID") {
                authenticateWithTouchID()
            }
            .padding()

            if let result = authenticationResult {
                CustomResultView(result: result)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }

    func authenticateWithTouchID() {
        let context = LAContext()

        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) {
            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Authenticate using Touch ID") { success, error in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if success {
                        authenticationResult = .success
                    } else {
                        authenticationResult = .failure
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            authenticationResult = .notAvailable
        }
    }
}

struct CustomResultView: View {
    let result: AuthenticationResult

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch result {
            case .success:
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                Text("Authentication Successful")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)

            case .failure:
                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                Text("Authentication Failed")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)

            case .notAvailable:
                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle")
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                Text("Touch ID not available or not configured")
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
            }
        }
    }
}

enum AuthenticationResult {
    case success
    case failure
    case notAvailable
}

@main
struct TouchIDExampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know SwiftUI, but won't this still show the system TouchID prompt?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about that and don't have a Mac to check that

Comment: The second call to `evaluatePolicy` will show the system TouchID prompt

Comment: My bad, then...